# How to route to a file in a folder with React Router?

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

My React app has a folder structure like this:

```
- src

-- pages
--- Home.js
--- Contact.js

--- project1
---- About.js
```

With React Router I can navigate to `Home.js` and `Contact.js` easily like this:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path='/'>
      <Home />
    </Route>
    <Route path='/contact-me'>
      <Contact />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

And click this to go to a page:

```
<Link to='/'>Home</Link>
<Link to='/contact-me'>Contact me</Link>
```

Now I would like to navigate to `About.js` inside project1 folder, how can I do it with React Router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the about page like you've imported the others

```
import About from '../pages/project1/About'

<Router>
 <Switch>
  <Route path='/'>
   <Home />
  </Route>
  <Route path='/contact-me'>
   <Contact />
  </Route>
  <Route path='/about-us'>
   <About />
  </Route>
 </Switch>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it like its done for Home and contact component
first import the component and then create your route.

```
import About from "./project1/About.js"
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path='/'>
      <Home />
    </Route>
    <Route path='/contact-me'>
      <Contact />
    </Route>
    <Route path='/about-me'>
      <About />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```